# I can't force quit an app (Wine)!

Tags: mac, applications

I installed Wine to open an .exe file on my Mac. I think I did something wrong and when I opened the file it installed to the Applications folder. Now, It doesn't let me force quit. I tried clicking "Force Quit" from the Apple menu and it didn't work. Now I can't turn my Mac off.

How can I force quit the Windows application running under Wine on my Mac?

Comment: If you want to force your Mac to turn off, hold the power button until it shuts off (about 10 seconds)

Comment: @Noah That's far too drastic of a measure for something like this.

Answer (score 4):

Use Terminal to kill the Wine process.

From the [Wine FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ)

> ### 10.2 Crashes and Freezes
>
> #### 10.2.1 My program froze up, how do I close it?
>
> If you ran the program from a terminal window by typing wine
> program.exe, you can usually just go back to that terminal window and
> press Ctrl+C. If you ran the application some other way, such as from
> a launcher shortcut, then you can open up a terminal and forcibly kill
> the process:
>
> ```
> killall -9 Application.exe
> ```
>
> If you want to kill all Wine programs at once, you can run:
>
> ```
> wineserver -k
> ```
>
> You can also open up a Wine version of the Windows task manager by
> running wine taskmgr in a terminal. This will allow you to kill
> individual Wine processes.

Comment: The command `wineserver -k` works fine with Wine 5.0 and Ubuntu 20.04, we should set a keyboard shortcut to it, to close fullscreen Wine program freezed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also open your activity monitor and kill it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If the traditional methods do not work, such as:

- Force quit from the app icon menu in the Dock
- Force quit from the apple menu
- Force quit from Alt + Command + Esc menu
- Finding the app and quitting it from the Activity monitor
- And you do not want to use the hard cold reboot by pressing and holding the Power button

You could try rebooting from the Terminal window and enter:

```
sudo reboot
```